# Javascript routing in play framework overrides other routes

Tags: playframework, url-routing

Defining routes in Play Framework, I noticed that if the order of the routes are:

```
GET    /javascriptRoutes           controllers.HomeController.javascriptRoutes
GET    /game/:number               controllers.HomeController.newItem(number: Int)
```

an AJAX request in the javascript won't run the method in my controller. When I switch the order of the routes:

```
GET    /game/:number               controllers.HomeController.newItem(number: Int)
GET    /javascriptRoutes           controllers.HomeController.javascriptRoutes
```

The AJAX request works fine. Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you please give us more details? Which URL is being requested? Are you getting a 404 or anything else? The only order you are changing are related to these two routes or there are other involved?

Comment: I tried replicating it and now the AJAX Request works fine. It might have been routes stepping over each other or server had to be reset.